# C - threads not returning to my destroy_threadpool function after finishing their job (Proxy server simulator w/ threads)

Tags: c, multithreading, server, proxy

So as the title says - my threads not returning to my destroy_threadpool function after finishing their job, causing my program to never end even after the max number of threads have been used.

While running the program, Valgrind says that 2 problems (each on specific function) occur during the thread work. I spent hours trying to figure out what can cause these problems, didn't find anything.. I'll include the parts of the code that I think are relevant, if you'll need more than that just let me know.

So those are my valgrind errors:

```
==32508== Invalid read of size 1
==32508==    at 0x10B96A: filter_address_from_string (proxyServer.c:654)
==32508==    by 0x10B38C: handle_conn (proxyServer.c:501)
==32508==    by 0x10C933: do_work (threadpool.c:232)
==32508==    by 0x4903B42: start_thread (pthread_create.c:442)
==32508==    by 0x4994BB3: clone (clone.S:100)

==31935== 74 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 8 of 21
==31935==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==31935==    by 0x10ADE5: read_file_content (proxyServer.c:240)
==31935==    by 0x10A93A: main (proxyServer.c:74)
```

And here are the relevant code parts:

```
char *read_file_content(const char *file_path) {
    FILE *file = fopen(file_path, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening file");
        return NULL;
    }

    // Get the size of the file
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    long file_size = ftell(file);
    if (file_size < 0) {
        perror("Error getting file size");
        fclose(file);
        return NULL;
    }
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    // Allocate memory for the content string
    char *content = (char *)malloc(file_size + 1); // +1 for null terminator
    if (content == NULL) {
        perror("Error allocating memory for file content");
        fclose(file);
        return NULL;
    }

    // Read the file content into the buffer
    size_t bytes_read_total = 0;
    size_t bytes_read;
    while ((bytes_read = fread(content + bytes_read_total, 1, file_size - bytes_read_total, file)) > 0) {
        bytes_read_total += bytes_read;
    }

    if (ferror(file)) {
        perror("ferror");
        free(content);
        fclose(file);
        return NULL;
    }

    // Null-terminate the content string
    content[bytes_read_total] = '\0';

    // Close the file before returning
    if (fclose(file) != 0) {
        perror("fclose");
        free(content);
        return NULL;
    }

    return content;
}


int filter_address_from_string(char *host, const char *file_content) {
    // Ensure host pointer is not NULL and points to a valid string
    if (host == NULL || *host == '\0' || file_content == NULL) {
        return -1;  // Invalid host
    }

    // iterating through filter file content
    while (*file_content != '\0') {
        // Find the end of the current line
        const char *end_of_line = strchr(file_content, '\n');
        if (end_of_line == NULL) {
//            end_of_line = file_content + strlen(file_content);  // Points to the null terminator
            end_of_line = strchr(file_content, '\0');
        }

        // Calculate the length of the current line
        size_t line_length = end_of_line - file_content;

        // Skip this line if it's too long
        if (line_length >= 256) {
            file_content = end_of_line + 1; // Move to the next line
            continue;
        }

        // Copy line from file content to local buffer
        char line[256];
        memcpy(line, file_content, line_length);
        line[line_length] = '\0'; // Null-terminate the line

        if (line[0] != '\0') {
            char *hostname_converted_to_ip = get_ipv4_address(host);
            if (hostname_converted_to_ip == NULL) {
                // Failed to convert hostname to IP, skip
                file_content = end_of_line + 1; // Move to the next line
                continue;
            }

            if (compare_host(host, line) == 0 || compare_host(hostname_converted_to_ip, line) == 0) {
                free(hostname_converted_to_ip);
                return 0;  // Match found in filter file
            }
            free(hostname_converted_to_ip);
        }

        file_content = end_of_line + 1; // Move to the next line
    }

    return 1;  // No match found in filter file
}


char *get_ipv4_address(const char *hostname) {
    struct addrinfo hints, *result, *rp;
    int status;

    // Setup hints to specify IPv4 and stream socket
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;      // Use IPv4
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; // Use a stream socket

    // Call getaddrinfo to get the list of addresses
    status = getaddrinfo(hostname, NULL, &hints, &result);
    if (status != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
        return NULL;
    }

    char *ipstr = NULL;

    // Find the first IPv4 address in the result
    for (rp = result; rp != NULL; rp = rp->ai_next) {
        if (rp->ai_family == AF_INET) {
            struct sockaddr_in *ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *) rp->ai_addr;
            ipstr = malloc(INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
            if (ipstr == NULL) {
                perror("malloc error");
                freeaddrinfo(result); // Free the allocated memory
                return NULL;
            }
            // Convert the IPv4 to a string
            inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(ipv4->sin_addr), ipstr, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
            break;
        }
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result); // Free the allocated memory

    if (ipstr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "No IPv4 address found for %s\n", hostname);
        return NULL; // Make sure to return NULL if no IPv4 address found
    }

    return ipstr;
}
```

The functions read_file_content() and filter_address_from_string() are called from my handle_conn() function, which is the function that each thread is sent to from my main. get_ipv4_address() is called by filter_address_from_string(), I included that because that may be a part of the problem to my understanding.

This is my whole handle_conn function: (I know that reading the client's GET request to a non dynamic allocated memory is bad practice, but it's not the point right now)

```
void handle_conn(void *arg) {
    int client_fd = (int) ((struct dispatch_args *) arg)->client_fd;
    char* filter_content = (char*) ((struct dispatch_args *) arg)->filter_file_content;

//    char response_buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
//    char *client_request = (char *)malloc(1);  // Dynamically allocated string
//    size_t requestSize = 0;
//    char *temp;
//    ssize_t bytes_received;
//    while ((bytes_received = read(client_fd, response_buffer, sizeof(response_buffer) - 1)) > 0) {
//        // Reallocate memory for the client_request string to accommodate the incoming data
//        temp = realloc(client_request, requestSize + bytes_received + 1);
//        if (temp == NULL) {
//            perror("Error reallocating memory");
//            // Handle error
//            break;
//        }
//        client_request = temp;
//
//        // Copy the received data to the client_request buffer
//        memcpy(client_request + requestSize, response_buffer, bytes_received);
//        requestSize += bytes_received;
//        client_request[requestSize] = '\0';  // Ensure null-termination
//
//        // Check if the delimiter "\r\n\r\n" is present in the client_request
//        if (strstr(client_request, "\r\n\r\n") != NULL) {
//            break;
//        }
//    }
//
//    if (bytes_received <= 0) {
//        close(client_fd);
//        free(client_request);  // Free the dynamically allocated memory
//        return;
//    }

// Placeholder for handling the client client_request
    char response_buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
    char client_request[3 * MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];  // Assuming a reasonable maximum size
    int requestSize = 0;

    ssize_t bytes_received;
    while ((bytes_received = read(client_fd, response_buffer, sizeof(response_buffer) - 1)) > 0) {
        // Check if there's enough space to accommodate the incoming data
        if (requestSize + bytes_received + 1 > sizeof(client_request)) {
            perror("Request size exceeds limit");
            break;
        }

        // Copy the received data to the client_request buffer
        strncpy(&client_request[requestSize], response_buffer, bytes_received);
        requestSize += (int) bytes_received;
        client_request[requestSize] = '\0';  // Ensure null-termination

        // Check if the delimiter "\r\n\r\n" is present in the client_request
        if (strstr(client_request, "\r\n\r\n") != NULL) {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (bytes_received <= 0) {
        close(client_fd);
        return;
    }



    printf("CLIENT REQUEST:\n%s\n", client_request);

    printf("method GET = %d\npath exist = %d\nprotocol exist = %d\n", is_method_exist(client_request),
           is_path_exist(client_request),
           is_protocol_exist(client_request));

    int method_flag = is_method_exist(client_request);
//    int path_flag = is_path_exist(client_request);
    int protocol_flag = is_protocol_exist(client_request);

    if (protocol_flag == 0) {
        // Send a 400 "Bad Request" response
        char *response = create_client_error("400 Bad Request", "Bad Request.");
        send(client_fd, response, strlen(response), 0);
        free(response);
//        free(client_request);
        close(client_fd);
        return;
    }

    char origin_host_name[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE]; // Assuming a maximum host name length of 255 characters
    int origin_port;

    get_origin_host_and_port(client_request, origin_host_name, &origin_port);

    printf("Origin Host Name: %s\n", origin_host_name);
    printf("Origin Port: %d\n", origin_port);

//    char *temp_host_header = strstr(origin_host_name, "Host: ");
//    if (temp_host_header == NULL) {
    if (strlen(origin_host_name) == 0) {
        // Send a 400 "Bad Request" response
        char *response = create_client_error("400 Bad Request", "Bad Request.");
        send(client_fd, response, strlen(response), 0);
        free(response);
        close(client_fd);
//        free(client_request);
        return;
    }

    printf("$$$got to here -2 $$$\n");

    // Check if the method is GET
    if (method_flag == 0) {
        // Send a 501 "Not Implemented" response
        char *response = create_client_error("501 Not Supported", "Method is not supported.");
        send(client_fd, response, strlen(response), 0);
        close(client_fd);
        free(response);
//        free(client_request);
        return;
    }

    printf("$$$got to here -1 $$$\n");

    // Connect to the origin server
    struct hostent *host_entry = gethostbyname(origin_host_name);
    if (host_entry == NULL) {
        char *response = create_client_error("404 Not Found", "File not found.");
        send(client_fd, response, strlen(response), 0);
        printf("error response:@@@\n%s\n", response);
        printf("I got to here $$$\n");
        free(response);
//        free(client_request);
        close(client_fd);
        return;
    }


    // Check for host/ip not on the list
    int filter_status = filter_address_from_string(origin_host_name, filter_content);
    if (filter_status == 0) {
        char *response = create_client_error("403 Forbidden", "Access denied.");
        send(client_fd, response, strlen(response), 0);
        free(response);
        close(client_fd);
//        free(client_request);
        return;
    }

    else if(filter_status == -1){
        char *response = create_client_error("500 Internal Server Error", "Some server side error.");
        send(client_fd, response, strlen(response), 0);
        free(response);
//        free(client_request);
        close(client_fd);
        return;
    }

    printf("$$$got to here 0 $$$\n");

    // Create a socket for origin server
    int origin_server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (origin_server_fd == -1) {
        char *response = create_client_error("500 Internal Server Error", "Some server side error.");
        send(client_fd, response, strlen(response), 0);
        free(response);
//        free(client_request);
        close(client_fd);
        return;
    }

    // Connect to origin server
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    memset(&server_address, 0, sizeof(server_address));
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(origin_port);
    server_address.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *) host_entry->h_addr);

    printf("$$$got to here 1 $$$\n");

    if (connect(origin_server_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &server_address, sizeof(server_address)) == -1) {
//        perror("500 Internal Server Error (connect)");
        char *response = create_client_error("500 Internal Server Error", "Some server side error.");
        send(client_fd, response, strlen(response), 0);
        free(response);
        close(origin_server_fd);
//        free(client_request);
        close(client_fd);
//        origin_server_fd = -1;  // Set to -1 to indicate failure
        return;
    }

    // close request connection
    close_connection_header(client_request);

    printf("$$$got to here 2 $$$\n");

    // Send client_request to origin server
    if (write(origin_server_fd, client_request, strlen(client_request)) == -1) {
//        perror("500 Internal Server Error (write)");
        char *response = create_client_error("500 Internal Server Error", "Some server side error.");
        send(client_fd, response, strlen(response), 0);
        free(response);
        close(origin_server_fd);
//        free(client_request);
        close(client_fd);
        return;
    }

    printf("$$$got to here 3 $$$\n");

    // Forward response from origin server to client
//    ssize_t origin_bytes_received = 0;
    ssize_t origin_bytes_received;
    char buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
    ssize_t bytes_sent;
    //read the data the client ask from the server in chunks
    while ((origin_bytes_received = read(origin_server_fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer))) > 0) {
        //sending the data from the server to the client
        bytes_sent = write(client_fd, buffer, origin_bytes_received);
        if (bytes_sent == -1) {
//            perror("500 Internal Server Error (write)");
            close(origin_server_fd);
            close(client_fd);
//            free(client_request);
            return;
        }
    }
    printf("$$$got to here 4 $$$\n");

    // Close the sockets and free the memory
    close(client_fd);
    close(origin_server_fd);
//    free(client_request);
}
```

Comment: Honestly, that's far too much code for a [mre] – and the function you ask for doesn't even seem to be mentioned in your code at all. How is it expected to get called otherwise? Instead of all that IO processing it appears to me much more relevant that you provide the code covering the thread management.

Comment: @Aconcagua I truly have no idea what parts of the code I can omit to make it more readable and informative for you.. IMO the whole handle_conn is relevant due to how I manage the memory over there.

Anyway, what did I miss? Valgrind mentioned 2 functions and I included them both (and an additional function that gets called)

Comment: Creating a [mre] typically is an iterative process, throwing away again and again parts of the code and testing if the problem still persists. What then ultimately remains is the [mre] you should post here (if yet needed at all, it's not uncommon that you might find the problem yourself during the course of creating the [mre]...).

Comment: Voting to close because of what Aconcagua said: You asked about a function named `destroy_threadpool`, but that name does not appear _anywhere_ in the almost 400 lines of code that you show. You also asked about some valgrind errors. That should be a separate question (or maybe two separate questions), and the one about "Invalid read..." may not be answerable if you do not show how `handle_conn` is called from `do_work`.

Comment: Also note: Your code example contains around 50 lines of commented-out source code. Please don't do that. Commented-out lines make it harder to read and understand the real code. Kind of like how camouflage clothing makes it harder to see a hunter in the bush.

Answer (score 0):

You asked three questions in one. You really should keep them separate in the future, but I'll take a stab at one of them. You showed a valgrind message:

> ```
>    ==31935== 74 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 8 of 21
>    ==31935==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
>    ==31935==    by 0x10ADE5: read_file_content (proxyServer.c:240)
>    ==31935==    by 0x10A93A: main (proxyServer.c:74)
> ```

That's telling you that `read_file_content` called `malloc`, and the program ended without ever `free`ing the allocated buffer.

That's not necessarily a problem, but it *could* be a problem. I have no way to tell because `read_file_content` was called from `main`, and I can't see your `main` function.

Lots of programs will allocate something *once* and then don't bother to `free` it before the program ends. But it would be a problem if the program *continually* allocates things without ever freeing them. In that case, the program could run the system out of memory (possibly impacting other programs) if it ran for long enough.

Anyway, if you don't want to see the message,* then `free()` the buffer that `read_file_content` allocated.

---

* In a large software project, you might be required to `free` the buffer even if it only ever was allocated one time. In a large project, tools like valgrind will be run again and again, maybe by automated scripts, throughout the life cycle of the product. When we do that, we want to get rid of every warning message, no matter how harmless, that we can possibly get rid of, because having to *explain* those warnings—having to reassure the management that they really are harmless—slows the whole process down.